# How to generate auto redirect of php page that takes one input variable to same page php with another input variable?

Tags: php, html

So I have a set of values let's say 90, 100, 110, 120, 130, 140, 150 The first time I load a php page, the value 90 is the main input variable and the page displays the details about 90. 
Now in 60 seconds the page redirects to the **same page** but with the input variable as 100. 
This continues on and when 150-related stuff is also displayed, it goes back to 90-related stuff.
How can this be achieved??

```
<?php

mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "qwerty") or die(mysql_error());

mysql_select_db("ups_status") or die(mysql_error());

$data = $_POST['input'] ;// <!--This is where the input should change after every redirect-->

$order = "SELECT * FROM ups_status1 WHERE (Ipaddress LIKE '%".$data."%')";

$results = mysql_query($order) or die('Invalid query: ' .mysql_error());

//    <!--And then I will echo the results-->

?>
```

Comment: always increment 10?

Comment: Hi and welcome to stack overflow. have you tried some code yourself first? if so - please edit your question and add it so we can help you debug it (don't put it in the comments, because code formatting is awful). If you haven't - please have a go yourself first... even if it's just pseudo code.

Comment: Use prepared statements or at least escape `$data` to prevent SQL injection attack vectors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['counter'])) {
    $_SESSION['counter'] = array(90, 100, 110, 120, 130, 140, 150);
}

$i = isset($_SESSION['i']) ? $_SESSION['i'] : 0;
echo "Variable is ".$_SESSION['counter'][$i];

/* Put your code here*/
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "qwerty") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("ups_status") or die(mysql_error());
$data = $_SESSION['counter'][$i] ;// <!--This is where the input should change after every redirect-->
$order = "SELECT * FROM ups_status1 WHERE (Ipaddress LIKE '%".$data."%')";
$results = mysql_query($order) or die('Invalid query: ' .mysql_error());
/*********************/

if ( $i == count($_SESSION['counter']) - 1) {
    $next = 0;
} else {
    $next = $i + 1;
}
$_SESSION['i'] = $next;
header( "refresh:5;url=refresh.php" );
echo '<br>You\'ll be redirected in about 5 secs. If not, click <a href="refresh.php">here</a>.';
?>
```

Comment: Everything seems fine except for the auto refresh part. Why do you think it might happen?

Comment: you can use other alternatives to redirect page to itself in your desired time like: jquery settimeout

Answer (score 1):

If always increase 10. Try this.

page.php

```
<?php
$id = isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : 90;
echo $id; // your code HERE
if($id < 150) {
    $nextId = $id +10;
    header("Refresh:60;url=page.php?id=" . $nextId);
} else {
    header("Refresh:60;url=page.php");
}
```

As you can see you can see in the access log every refresh (I did the test every 5 sec)

[image]

Comment: I cannot even begin to explain what is wrong with this code....do you realize what this code does? sleep(60); ??? so wait 60 seconds before you execute something... in PHP?

Comment: this should work, I undid my down vote. The first answer was really bad.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use Location header as it will prevent you from showing output first. Use Refresh instead since you're refreshing the same page..

you can store the variable in a session or just simply pass as the page refresh.

Here the php page is named page.php and it will refresh every 5 seconds and passess the variable to itself. Once it reloaded it will simply increment the pass variable or reset it to 90 when it's > 150.

```
  <?php

       $data = isset($_GET['input']) ? $_GET['input'] : 90;
       echo "Value is ".$data;
       $data = ($input >= 150) ? 90: $data;
       header( "refresh:5;url=page.php?input=".($data+10));
?>
```

To try: Copy this code to a file named page.php and open in browser.

update:

assuming your code example works. you can just modify the line below

```
$data = $_POST['input']
```

to

```
$data = isset($_GET['input']) ? $_GET['input'] : 90;
```

then add a refresh header after you've done your output.

```
$data = ($data >= 150) ? 90: $data;
header( "refresh:60;url=page.php?input=".$data );
```

Comment: if you update the vaue $value before the echo it will always display 10 more. For ex. whenever $value=150, it will dispay 160

Comment: it will never reach 150. also, the previous value is what's being incremented.

Comment: i meant it will never reach beyond 150 in the code example.

Comment: you might want to change your comment from `<!--And then I will echo the results-->` to `//And then I will echo the results`

Comment: The first time I am selecting 90 as my input, the results of 100 are being displayed when i ran ur code Keith!!

Comment: my assumption was 90 will always the first, so there's no need to put an input and the first call is just "page.php". a quick fix should do.

Comment: anyway, i've modified it, so if no input pass it will default to 90. gooduck.

Comment: Ok thanks... its working fine with yours ! :) Keith!